# Exception creating new Maven project in Apache Netbeans9

Tags: java, apache, maven, exception, netbeans

I faced this exception when I create a new `maven` project in Apache `Netbeans9`, I'm using `Java10`.

Here is the exception text:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key contains code point U+0000
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.get(AbstractPreferences.java:296)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.queries.MavenFileOwnerQueryImpl.registerCoordinates(MavenFileOwnerQueryImpl.java:153)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.ProjectOpenedHookImpl.registerWithSubmodules(ProjectOpenedHookImpl.java:431)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.ProjectOpenedHookImpl.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHookImpl.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:60)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.notifyOpened(OpenProjectList.java:1273)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.doOpenProject(OpenProjectList.java:1354)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.open(OpenProjectList.java:798)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$6.run(OpenProjectList.java:650)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

**Screenshot**
 [image: this is the screenshot of the exception]

Comment: Please copy and add the error with your question. Image links are not considered good for simple errors texts.

Comment: Maven is working for me with NetBeans 9, but your error looks similar to unresolved [Netbeans Bug 271715 - IllegalArgumentException: Key contains code point U+0000](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271715), although that occurs when opening an 8.2 Maven project under 9.0 rather than when creating a 9.0 Maven project. It might be worth reviewing your Maven settings: **Tools > Options > Java >** select the **Maven** tab. Also, check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) for exceptions.

Comment: Facing the same issue: when opening or creating any maven project with Netbeans 9 on JDK 10 (Oracle or even openjdk) I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key contains code point U+0000
 at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.get(AbstractPreferences.java:296)

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: It might concern https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8075156 When loading preferences for Maven module some key in NbPreferences contains U+0000 Operating system Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

Finally, workaround found!

You (and me as well) used Netbeans of older versions, so Netbeans keeps old preferences and settings like DB connections, AppServers, installed modules and so on at
`C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\`

... and tries to import it. Possibly any of your preferences or settings containes wrong data. Just remove or rename this directory and start for fresh.

Be aware: all you preferences will be lost!

Another approach: you can search patterm `\u0000` (just as text) in all files at older configurations. In my case two files were containing lines

`\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`

at the very begining. Removing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the NetBeans folder from `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\`
solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks. In my case this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this file was corrupt.

```
C:\Users\[your_name]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\maven\externalOwners.properties
```

I deleted it and recreated it as an empty file. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu workaround to remove local netbeans data

```
rm -rf ~/.netbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to migrate from Netbeans 12.1 (under jdk8) to Netbeans 12.5 (under jdk11).

Encountered this exception.

I tried S. Kadakov's answer, did found some files containing `\u0000` control characters like `uihandler.properties` but removing these characters didn't really do anything.

Instead what I did is go to the installation folder (in my case)

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.5\netbeans\etc
```

And modified the `netbeans_jdkhome` setting

```
#netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11"
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261"
```

Basically telling Netbeans to go back to jdk8.
If you have code that needs to be compiled with a higher JDK you can just set the right java platform for the compiler inside the IDE itself

Answer (score 0):

Close your Netbeans IDE and - C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming\

Just remove or rename the NetBeans folder. Then relaunch your IDE and open the project via file - open menu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).