# Cannot run Apache Netbeans 11 using JDK 11

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11

No matter what I do, I can't get Netbeans 11 to work with JDK 11. Can you help me out?

Please note that this issue does NOT occur with JDK 8.

Downloaded and installed JDK 11 to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4

Downloaded and unzipped Netbeans 11 to C:\Program Files\netbeans

The etc/netbeans.conf file has been edited to set JDK home:

> netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4"

When trying to run bin/netbeans64.exe:

> First time: The loading window appears, loads for a bit, and then the
>   whole program disappears.
>
> Second time: Loading window does not appear. An empty Java application
>   appears.
>
> If I go to Task Manager and manually end the Netbeans process, I can
>   get back to First time.

**For the attachments listed below, please refer to the issue I created here:**
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2865

Executing netbeans64.exe from PowerShell outputs error messages to the console. They can be found in consoleOutput.txt attachment.

The results from executing bin/netbeans64.exe --trace C:\netbeans.log can be found in netbeans.log attachment.

For reference, this is the tutorial I followed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxh-hVty09g

**Update & Solution**

I FINALLY got it to work thanks to the answer provided by skomisa.

The issue was caused by Netbeans 11.0 importing settings from a previous version. There was a popup the first time I ran Netbeans 11.0 asking if I wanted to import my settings from a previous version. Refer to skomisa's answer for more details on why.

To solve it, I deleted ALL of the preference files for NetBeans 11 by deleting the entire folder in AppData.

> C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0\

Skomisa's answer mentioned trying to create a new unzipped version of NetBeans 11 and not importing the settings. I had actually tried this previously, but never got the popup window asking if you want to import. I assume this is because the user preference files for this version of NetBeans have already been created and are still sitting in AppData.

This leaves you with two viable options:

1. Delete all of the user preference files for NetBeans 11.0.
2. Search through the entire folder for instances of `\u0000` and remove them.

It seemed easier and more satisfactory to remove the entire folder and start from scratch. That way, all of my user preference files are using the newest practices accepted by the JDK and Netbeans and that, hopefully, there is no lingering legacy code that will randomly break the next time I update.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Have you tried running it with 11.0.2?

Comment: @Sedrick No, I haven't. Just went to the Oracle archives and started the download. Will report back with results

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME properly configured as well?

Comment: @Sedrick Same results with 11.0.2

Comment: @Villat The only JAVA_HOME I have set is in the netbeans.conf file. Is there another I need to set?

Comment: @Villat Just realized you're probably talking about system environment variables. I don't believe I've set that. How do I do so properly?

Comment: @HunterS try to set JAVA_HOME on your Windows environment variables as well

Comment: @HunterS here you go https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Comment: @Villat Thanks. I set JAVA_HOME and still got the same results. I tried setting to both 11.0.2 and 11.0.4. I know I did it right because executing javac -version outputs `javac 11.0.4` and executing java -version outputs `java version "1.8.0_221"` (I have Java 8 JRE installed on pc)

Comment: @HunterS well, in fact, *java -version* should be 11.0.4, so you're not setting your JAVA_HOME properly. Remember that you need to add the %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well

Comment: @Villat I added screenshots to the question description

Comment: @HunterS remove the first line from the PATH, c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Comment: Hmm, clear exception in that log that relates to the preferences API, but whether that's the cause of the program crashing out is hard to say.

Comment: @Villat I removed the first line. java -version is now 11.0.4 like you said. Netbeans still crashes though

Comment: @HunterS sorry, I don't know what it could be then. Try to reboot your PC with the new configuration, or reinstall Netbeans, but it's weird.

Comment: @Villat Still no luck. I appreciate the help though

Comment: Actually your solution - just delete all user preferences - was the cleanest of all. And you are correct that once you have imported your settings, merely reinstalling NetBeans to a different directory won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem appears to be related to the `IllegalArgumentException` ("*Key contains code point U+0000*") in the console log output of your bug report. It looks like NetBeans is trying to import your preferences from an earlier release of Netbeans, and is is finding some invalid null character(s) in your preference file(s).

This has been bug reported before, but remains unresolved. See [Bug 271652 - IllegalArgumentException: Key contains code point U+0000](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271652).

Your preference files are all XML files (with extension **xml**), and reside in various directories under **C:\Users\user ID\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0\config**.

In my case my only preference file for NetBeans 11 is named **C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0\config\Editors\text\x-java\Preferences\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml** but you may have more than one.

From the stack trace in your console log, the failing call is `AbstractPreferences.getBoolean()`, so the null is probably on a line containing `Boolean` in your preference file. However, [as this somewhat related SO answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51615036/2985643), just blindly remove all nulls from all preference files. Nulls should never exist in any XML file anyway.

An alternative approach to solving your problem is to create a new unzipped version of NetBeans 11, but do not import your settings.

I suppose you could even locate the preference files in your existing (broken) NB 11 installation and delete them, though that seems like an unsatisfactory approach even if it works.

A few related points:

- Seeing the NetBeans window appear briefly before it vanishes is often a symptom of having set **netbeans_jdkhome** to an invalid JDK path, but in your case the value looks fine.
- **JAVA_HOME** is ignored by NetBeans, so that cannot be the cause of your problem. See the response to [Bug 198950 - NetBeans should use the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables, if available, to determine which JDK to use](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198950) for details on how NetBeans decides which JDK to use. Specifying the **--jdkhome** parameter when you start NetBeans will override everything else.
- The `IllegalArgumentException` only arises with JDK versions >= 9 because of a JDK bug fix, but that's a good thing. See [JDK-8075156 : (prefs) get*() and remove() should disallow the use of the null control character '\u0000' as key](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8075156) for details. You weren't getting the problem with NetBeans 8.x because you probably weren't ever importing any preference files, but even if you were the `IllegalArgumentException` would not have occurred due to the Java bug fixed by JDK-8075156.