# Apache NetBeans 11.3 won't start after Windows update, Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans

After having a Windows update unable to update my machine, it did an auto roll back and, for some reason, now I can't start Apache NetBeans 11.3. I checked my path and everything looks fine. I know for sure it's a Windows update issue, because NetBeans was open the day before and I had my laptop on hibernation only. Now, I only get a minimized screen with the Java logo on top. The window is completely white if I maximize it. I do have something on NetBeans log, but I'm not sure what it means. Can anyone take a look at it? Maybe I'm missing something.

Log in messages.txt from NetBeans, I can't paste all the code here, but it can be found inside the link

https://pastebin.com/uA8JQ0nb

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Wednesday, May 11, 2022 at 10:07:25 AM Central Daylight Time
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Apache NetBeans IDE 11.3
  Operating System        = Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 14.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 14.0.1+7; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 14.0.1+7
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
  System Locale; Encoding = es_MX (nb); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\Patron
  Current Directory       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3
  User Directory          = C:\Users\Patron\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.3
  Cache Directory         = C:\Users\Patron\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3
  Installation            = C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\nb
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\ergonomics
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\ide
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\extide
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\java
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\apisupport
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\webcommon
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\websvccommon
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\enterprise
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\profiler
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\php
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\harness
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\groovy
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\javafx
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = 
  Application Classpath   = C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-ui.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-
```

UPDATE EDIT: i did follow skomisa advice and yes my question is a duplicate of an older question, i did erase my user preferences from appdata/roaming/netbeans and now the ide launches, but all my config is gone as well im unable to start my project, but anyway i was already checking VS code so im moving into that direction, im leaving netbeans for good, thanks.

Comment: Install Netbeans again.

Comment: The relevant error message is _"IllegalArgumentException: Key contains code point U+0000"_ near the end of your log extract that you posted on pastebin. That can happen if you have nulls in user files needed by the NetBeans upgrade process, and arises from a JDK bug fix. See SO question [Cannot run Apache Netbeans 11 using JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57084144/2985643) for more information. I think your question is a duplicate of that one, but update your question accordingly if it doesn't resolve your issue.