# How do I track down this exception in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I had zero issues installing Java and NetBeans  on my Windows 10 desktop which is an older Alienware. I need to get it onto my laptop (also Windows 10) and I have tried numerous versions of JDKs, along with a couple different versions of NetBeans.

Always, the behaviour is as follows: When I start NetBeans after installing it, the screen pops up, the progress bar show modules loading, etc., and then towards the end of the travel of the progress bar, the whole program disappears from the desktop. In [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)), it still shows as a process somehow, but you can’t switch to it.

Here is the log showing the exception. How can I fix it?

```
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.laf]: USG_LOOK_AND_FEEL
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key contains code point U+0000
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.get(AbstractPreferences.java:291)
    at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.getBoolean(AbstractPreferences.java:526)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.TopComponentTracker.load(TopComponentTracker.java:76)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.PersistenceHandler.load(PersistenceHandler.java:101)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.load(WindowSystemImpl.java:56)
    at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:200)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Write to
```

Comment: that's an issue of netbeans itself by the looks of it. The netbeans.core.windows.TopComponentTracker tries to load some preferences (typically .preference files) which seem to contain illegal characters, e.g. wrong file encoding. Maybe you can find the internal preference files of it and check or delete them. Could be leftovers from previous installations or something like that.

Comment: Thank you , I will give this a try if I get some time tonight.

Comment: There are a couple of questions that address this issue in older versions of NetBeans. See [Cannot run Apache Netbeans 11 using JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57084144/2985643) and [Exception creating new Maven project in Apache Netbeans9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51244824/2985643). It looks like a failed installation process somehow put some null character(s) in your preference file(s). Hence the _Key contains code point U+0000_ message in your stack trace. Since they are XML/properties files the solution is to remove the null(s) from those file(s), or just delete those files.

Comment: ...File deletion is simpler, since it does not look like you have any data worth keeping. Just delete everything under **C:\Users\{_User ID_}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\{_NetBeans version_}\config**, and then attempt to  reinstall NetBeans. As a related matter, since this looks like an issue with the NetBeans installer, and you are not upgrading, you could bypass the problem completely by downloading the ZIP bundling of NetBeans instead. Just unzip that download to a directory and your installation is complete!

Comment: Meta discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420858/should-this-self-answer-by-a-new-poster-have-been-deleted-in-review?cb=1

Comment: @Neil I thought your answer had been unfairly deleted and raised the issue on StackOverflow Meta. Apparently it was deleted during a review because it contained a lot of "fluff", but the consensus was that deletion was unduly harsh, so your answer was restored without that fluff. Just FYI, try to keep your questions and answers sharply focused on the problem. For example, never write things like _"I am new..."_ or _"I couldn't find anything on google..."_, and never use _"please"_ in your question or _"thanks"_ in your answer. That is simply the way things are done here.

Answer (score 19):

I solved this by deleting the recommended folder, `C:\Users\{User ID}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\{NetBeans version}\config`, as well as the rest of the NetBeans directory. It had already been uninstalled but, apparently, the directory remained from a previous attempt.

To reinstall it properly, I downloaded the ZIP file of the binaries. It seemed to be an issue with the installer itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you have older versions of NetBeans installed and/or have used the import options in the first run of this version, then

- removing the cache directory might fix the problem. The cache dir is
  visible in the Menu `Help -> About`.
- Another try is remove the user dir, visible at the same Menu.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have netbeans installed previously, but I have tried installing it numerous times, and most recently an older version, so I am sure there are traces of garbage left over. I will check the locations you point to. Thanks again

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). Answers are not for clarifying questions. Rhetorical questions ought to be converted to statements.